# How to convert word to html using power tool xml

Tags: c#, power-tools-for-xml

I'm using `PowerToolXml.dll` as a reference to convert word to HTML this is my code

```
using OpenXmlPowerTools;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(DocxFilePath);
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
    {
        HtmlConverterSettings settings = new HtmlConverterSettings()
        {
            PageTitle = "My Page Title"
        };
        XElement html = HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(doc, settings);

        File.WriteAllText(HTMLFilePath, html.ToStringNewLineOnAttributes());
    }
}
```

But produces error at `WordprocessingDocument` this is not referred (i.e it produce not reference error) how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a reference to `powertoolxml` in your project?

Comment: i'm using the above code only no other reference i used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The sample code uses the classes and enumerations that are in the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll assembly that is installed with the Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office. To add the reference to the assembly in the following steps or to build the sample code that accompanies this visual how-to, you must first download and install the Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office so that the assembly is available

You'll find the link to the article below but for your convenience I have summarised it here:

The reference must be made inside your Visual Studio project.  In Solution Explorer, find your project; then expand it; look for **References**; expand it; and ensure `PowerToolXml` appears there;  if not right-click **References** and **Add Reference** to the assembly

### Tell me more

- [Using the Open XML SDK 2.0 Classes Versus Using .Net XML Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361882(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, i solved the above problem by adding required dll correctly it works correctly but it loses alignment of the word document otherwise it converts correctly word document to html